# @NumberFormat Annotation for console

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, annotations

I'm using

```
 @NumberFormat(style = Style.CURRENCY)
 private Double value = 50.00;
```

in my Spring MVC project. As per the reference documentation,
     "mvc:annotation-driven"

is enough to bind default formatters like @NumberFormat. And I am successfully getting it displayed in my JSP but when I try to print it to console in my controller by

```
System.out.println(value);
```

It doesn't format the value at all. In my research, I found multiple examples for JSP but none for console. Why does it not format the number in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method arguments are passed by value in Java. If you call a method like `println`, you are just passing the *value* of the member variable named `value` - not the variable itself.

The `println` method has no way of knowing where the value came from, so there is no way for it to know that it came from the member variable named `value`, which happens to have an annotation - the `println` method can't inspect the variable itself and discover the annotation, since it doesn't know where the value comes from.

When you do this in a JSP, you are not using plain Java method calls, you're probably using some Spring-specific tag to which you pass the name of the variable. The Spring tag handler will then lookup the variable and find the annotation, which it uses to determine how to format the value.